# I am getting sonarqube codecoverage repot 0% I installed all recent version applications

Tags: eclipse-plugin, code-coverage, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.1

Jococo.exec file is creating after maven build in target folder, but getting code coverage 0% and added plugins of both sonarqube and jococo.

I tried added report dependies and I refered all sites and yt videos I am not able to get this code coverage.
I am expection to solve issue and get code coverage percentage.

[image]

Comment: Are the tests executed in the Maven build? Please show your project structure and settings about your tests. Do you use JUnit 4 or 5?

Comment: Maven Build is success for both jococo and Sonar goals , and Sonarqube is also up and sonar scanner execution success

Comment: Please improve your question with all the information I am asked for. Why does your question not mention that it works in the Maven build and shows how it looks like? Is the test code compiled and executed (What if there is a compile error? What if there is failing test?)?